# How to non-interactively provide password to SCP, rsync FTP, SFTP?

Tags: linux, shell-script

How can I supply a password on the command line or in a script rather than on an interactive prompt?

I need to copy files in a script and lets say public key is not copied yet to the target.

OS is any version of Unix, like HP-UX, Linux, Solaris etc.

One more thing: if I have to copy public key to a different machine, if say there are 100 users, then I need to copy the public key to 100 different users' 
`$HOME/user/.ssh/authorizedkeys` for a passwordless login.

Is there any way around this by modifying the `root`'s authorized keys or `known_hosts`?

Comment: Please user proper capitalization in your posts ("i" should be "I", "ftp" is "FTP", etc). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say there are 2 options.. 1 you've already alluded to being the exchange of public keys.

The other is to investigate a small utility called 'expect'.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

I'm sure this will do what you *expect* it to :)

See here for a good example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-bash-script-to-provide-password-to-ssh-command